# Flutter multiple if-statement

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart, google-play

I have the following multiple if-statement in my flutter app:

```
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Info and Comms').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[8]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Media').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[10]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Utilities').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[16]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Education').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[4]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Repairs').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[13]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Domestic Help').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[3]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Transport').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[15]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Manufacturing').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[9]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Mining').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[11]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Supply Chain').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[14]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Government').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[6]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Financial and Business Services').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[5]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Construction').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[2]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Agriculture').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[1]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Wholesale and Retail Trade').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[17]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Accomodation').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[0]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Health Social and Personal').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[7]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text(text1).toString()==Text('Movement').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[12]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
        Text('Data not found').toString(),
```

When deploying on my mobile device, it works perfect but after launching on Play Store, it returns the first statement regardless.

Any idea why this is now broken and where to start fixing?

*****EDIT*****

Added Category Page content where if-statement is located.
Original CategoryPage Code:

```
 class CategoryPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String text1;
  final String text2;
  final String text3;
  CategoryPage(
      {Key key,
      @required this.text1,
      @required this.text2,
      @required this.text3})
      : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(text2),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      body: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Current Level ' + text3.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    //color: Colors.red[900],
                    color: Text(text3).toString() == Text("5").toString()
                        ? Colors.red[900]
                        : Text(text3).toString() == Text("4").toString()
                            ? Colors.orange[900]
                            : Text(text3).toString() == Text("3").toString()
                                ? Colors.brown[300]
                                : Text(text3).toString() == Text("2").toString()
                                    ? Colors.blue[300]
                                    : Text(text3).toString() == Text("1").toString()
                                        ? Colors.green[300]
                                        : Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
           Container(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                text1.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    //color: Colors.red[900],
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Text(text3).toString() == Text('1').toString()
              ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level1').snapshots()
              : Text(text3).toString() == Text('2').toString()
                  ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level2').snapshots()
                  : Text(text3).toString() == Text('3').toString()
                      ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level3').snapshots()
                      : Text(text3).toString() == Text('4').toString()
                          ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level4').snapshots()
                          : Text(text3).toString() == Text('5').toString()
                              ? Firestore.instance
                                  .collection('Level5')
                                  .snapshots()
                              : Firestore.instance
                                  .collection('Level1')
                                  .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text('Loading data ...');
            } else {
              return Text(
                //snapshot.data.documents[0]['desc'].toString(),
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Info and Comms').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[8]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Media').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[10]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Utilities').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[16]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Education').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[4]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Repairs').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[13]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Domestic Help').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[3]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Transport').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[15]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Manufacturing').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[9]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Mining').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[11]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Supply Chain').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[14]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Government').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[6]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Financial and Business Services').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[5]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Construction').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[2]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Agriculture').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[1]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Wholesale and Retail Trade').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[17]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Accomodation').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[0]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Health Social and Personal').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[7]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text(text1).toString()==Text('Movement').toString()?(snapshot.data.documents[12]['desc'].toString()).replaceAll("/n", "\n"):
                Text('Data not found').toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300])),
      ),]
      ));
  }

}
```

*****UPDATE*****
After simplifying if-statement following Yann39 advice - code works perfectly fine on my side when deploying from Visual Code onto my phone but still does not work when downloading the app from Google Play Store.

Updated CategoryPage:

```
class CategoryPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String text1;
  final String text2;
  final String text3;
  CategoryPage(
      {Key key,
      @required this.text1,
      @required this.text2,
      @required this.text3})
      : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(text2),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      body: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Current Level ' + text3.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    //color: Colors.red[900],
                    color: Text(text3).toString() == Text("5").toString()
                        ? Colors.red[900]
                        : Text(text3).toString() == Text("4").toString()
                            ? Colors.orange[900]
                            : Text(text3).toString() == Text("3").toString()
                                ? Colors.brown[300]
                                : Text(text3).toString() == Text("2").toString()
                                    ? Colors.blue[300]
                                    : Text(text3).toString() == Text("1").toString()
                                        ? Colors.green[300]
                                        : Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
           Container(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                text1.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    //color: Colors.red[900],
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Text(text3).toString() == Text('1').toString()
              ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level1').snapshots()
              : Text(text3).toString() == Text('2').toString()
                  ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level2').snapshots()
                  : Text(text3).toString() == Text('3').toString()
                      ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level3').snapshots()
                      : Text(text3).toString() == Text('4').toString()
                          ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level4').snapshots()
                          : Text(text3).toString() == Text('5').toString()
                              ? Firestore.instance
                                  .collection('Level5')
                                  .snapshots()
                              : Firestore.instance
                                  .collection('Level1')
                                  .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text('Loading data ...');
            } else {
              return Text(DocumentUtils.getDocumentDescriptionFromTitle(snapshot, text1.toString()),style: TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.white,
                     fontSize: 15,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                 textAlign: TextAlign.left,);
            }
          },
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300])),
      ),]
      ));
  }

}

class DocumentUtils {

  static String getDocumentDescriptionFromTitle(AsyncSnapshot snapshot, String title) {
    var map = {
      'Info and Comms':8,
      'Media':10,
      'Utilities':16,
      'Education':4,
      'Repairs':13,
      'Domestic Help':3,
      'Transport':15,
      'Manufacturing':9,
      'Mining':11,
      'Supply Chain':14,
      'Government':6,
      'Financial and Business Services':5,
      'Construction':2,
      'Agriculture':1,
      'Wholesale and Retail Trade':17,
      'Accomodation':0,
      'Health Social and Personal':7,
      'Movement':12,
    };
    return map[title] != null ? snapshot.data.documents[map[title]]['desc'].toString().replaceAll("/n", "\n") : 'Data not found';
  }

}
```

*****UPDATE******

After the above if-statement simplify, the correct category discriptions are displayed, but now it only returns Collection 'Level1' from Firestore :

```
stream: Text(text3).toString() == Text('1').toString()
              ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level1').snapshots()
              : Text(text3).toString() == Text('2').toString()
                  ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level2').snapshots()
                  : Text(text3).toString() == Text('3').toString()
                      ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level3').snapshots()
                      : Text(text3).toString() == Text('4').toString()
                          ? Firestore.instance.collection('Level4').snapshots()
                          : Text(text3).toString() == Text('5').toString()
                              ? Firestore.instance
                                  .collection('Level5')
                                  .snapshots()
                              : Firestore.instance
                                  .collection('Level1')
                                  .snapshots(),
```

The above multiple if-statement works fine when deploying the app on my device, it is only when installing the app from Play Store which gives me these issues with the multiple if-statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it does not answer directly your question (it is too long for a comment) but I'm not sure to understand why you are using `Text(text1).toString() == Text('text').toString()` instead of `text1 == 'text'` directly ?

Also note that `Text(text3).toString()` will return the string "Text(text3)", not the contained text. If you want to get the contained text use `Text(text3).data`. But once again you shouldn't have to create `Text` widgets here, `text1 == 'text'` should do the job, it is much more simple and performant.

I would have also simplified thoses `if` repetitions into a function, for example (assuming that you don't have the documents titles in `snapshot.data.documents` then you would not need the map to do the mapping) :

```dart
class DocumentUtils {

  static String getDocumentDescriptionFromTitle(AsyncSnapshot<YourObject> snapshot, String title) {
    var map = {
      'Info and Comms':8,
      'Media':10,
      'Utilities':16,
      'Education':4,
      'Repairs':13,
      'Domestic Help':3,
      'Transport':15,
      'Manufacturing':9,
      'Mining':11,
      'Supply Chain':14,
      'Government':6,
      'Financial and Business Services':5,
      'Construction':2,
      'Agriculture':1,
      'Wholesale and Retail Trade':17,
      'Accomodation':0,
      'Health Social and Personal':7,
      'Movement':12,
    };
    return map[title] != null ? snapshot.data.documents[map[title]]['desc'].toString().replaceAll("/n", "\n") : 'Data not found';
  }

}
```

So that in your widget you just have to call `DocumentUtils.getDocumentDescriptionFromTitle(snapshot, text1)`.

If you have the documents titles in your `snapshot.data.documents` then it would be something like :

```dart
class DocumentUtils {

  static String getDocumentDescriptionFromTitle(AsyncSnapshot<YourObject> snapshot, String title) {
    return snapshot.data.documents.firstWhere((Document d) => d.title == title)['desc'].replaceAll("/n", "\n");
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yann39 - It does make sense to simplify the if-statement. I have added the full page code in my post as I cannot figure out what needs to go into "YourObject" in your code (Still a noob). If I change as you suggested to text1=='text', I get an error from firebase "type 'Text' is not a subtype of type 'String'.

Comment: `YourObject` is the type of `snapshot.data`. To simplify you could use `getDocumentDescriptionFromTitle(YourSnapshotDataType data, String title)` then simply return `return data.documents[...]...`. Concerning texts comparison, your text1 is declared as `final String text1` so I really can't see why you couldn't compare it directly to any string, but I don't use Firebase so I don't know if it does something special here.

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the if-statement and tested it on my device. Works perfect. I will be updating the Google Playstore and hopefully it would sort out that issue. Strange why it would work on local but doesnt work when downloading it from Play Store.

Comment: Seems like the issue is still not resolved after simplifying the if-statement, unfortunitely.

Comment: Strange, I think the problem is somewhere else than in the if statement. Maybe related to Firebase configuration for APK release. But I'm afraid I can't help with this as I don't use Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far Yann39, the update you proposed seems to be pulling the correct category description, but for some reason, the Firebase collection seems to be wrong. This is where I build the stream in StreamBuilder which also contains a multiple if statement. I tried simplifying it as you suggested with the categories but Im having issues assigning parameter "stream" to Text. Could you please help simplify that if-statement also?

Comment: It seems to always go into Level1. Again, the code runs fine when deploying it on my device. It is only when I download the app from Play Store that I have these issues. It makes testing impossible.

Comment: `Text(text3).toString()` will return the string "Text(text3)", not the contained text. If you want to get the contained text use `Text(text3).data`. But once again you shouldn't have to create `Text` widgets here, `text3 == '1'` should do the job, it is much more simple and performant. I also note that you sometimes use double quotes and sometimes use simple quotes for strings, they works the same but try to be consistent, the [Flutter style guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo#prefer-single-quotes-for-strings) recommends using single quotes ;)

Comment: And to simplify your if statement : if value '1' for `text3` must always return instance of collection 'Level1', '2' instance of collection 'Level2', and so on, then simply use the following function : `void getFirebaseStream(String text) { return Firestore.instance.collection('Level$text').snapshots(); }` then set your stream as : `stream: getFirebaseStream(text3)`.

Comment: I'm getting an error "A value of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot> can't be returned from function 'getFirebaseStream' because it has a return type of 'void'.dart(return_of_invalid_type)"

Comment: Oh yes of course  I cannot test the code so I set `void` as return type but you have to set the righ one which indeed should be `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`.

Comment: Thanks Yann39! Work perfectly when deploying on my device. Will release update and advise as soon as it becomes available for download. Thanks again for your help so far, you've saved me countless of hours.

Comment: Works perfectly with download from Play Store, thanks Yann39!!

Comment: Glad it helped you. Best.